# Create a varible with condition inside Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a next code:

```
export const FormComponent = () => {
...
return (
   ...
 <Formik
          validationSchema={nameEmailValidationSchema}
          initialValues={{ name: '', email: '' }}
          onSubmit={(values) => {console.log(values)}}
        >
          {({
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            values,
            touched,
            errors,
            isValid = false,
          }) => (
...

              {isValid && values.name && values.email ? (
                  <View style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
                    <AppButtonComponent
                      title="Save"
                      backgroundColor={Colors.primaryColor}
                      color={Colors.white}
                      onPress={handleSubmit}
                    />
                  </View>
                ) : null}

....
)}
        </Formik>
)

}
```

How can I create a variable with condition `isValid && values.name && values.email` such as `let showButton = isValid && values.name && values.email;` and paste it inside code instead of condition.
Thanks in adnvance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In arrow function you can write it multiple way, for example

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b
// or
const add = (a, b) => (a + b)
```

this function instantly return result of `a + b`. But you don't need to shorten it. You can still do

```
const add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}
```

So instead of

```
  <Formik ...yourFormikProps...>
    {({
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        ...
        values,
        isValid = false,
    }) => (
       <YourView>....</YourView>
    )
</Formik>
```

You can do

```
<Formik ...yourFormikProps...>
    {({
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        ...
        values,
        isValid = false,
    }) => {
       const showButton = isValid && values.name && values.email;
       return (
         <YourView>
           {showButton ? <Button>Save</Button> : null}
         </YourView>
      )
   }
</Formik>
```

...